# Fetching unique membership in a MySQL many-to-many table

Tags: mysql, join, many-to-many

MySQL here. I'm building a super simple chat feature for my web app and have cooked up the following data model for it:

```
describe users;
+----------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id                    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username                   | varchar(36)         | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+----------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

describe conversations;
+-------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                   | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| conversation_id         | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| conversation_created_on | datetime            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

describe users_x_conversations;
+-----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| users_x_conversations | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id               | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| conversation_id       | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

describe messages;
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| message_id      | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| conversation_id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| sender_id       | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| message_text    | text                | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| message_sent_at | datetime            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

So above, a **conversation** will be a container for 1+ **messages** sent back and forth between **users**.

I'm now trying to write a query that determines if a list of users have an existing conversation with each other (I don't want to allow duplicate conversations between the exact same list of users). So say my `users_x_conversations` table looked like:

```
user_id | conversation_id
------- | --------
1           3
2           3
3           3
1           4
3           4
2           5
```

I want to be able to determine that users 1, 2 and 3 all have an existing conversation started (`conversation_id = 3`).

So far, the best query I can come up with is:

```
SELECT *
FROM conversations c
INNER JOIN users_x_conversations uxc
ON c.conversation_id = uxc.conversation_id
WHERE uxc.user_id IN ( 1,2,3 )
```

But that returns ALL conversations that users 1, 2 and 3 are members of, *not* the single conversation that they are all party to.

Any ideas where I'm going awry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT c.*
FROM conversations c
INNER JOIN users_x_conversations uxc
ON c.conversation_id = uxc.conversation_id
WHERE uxc.user_id IN ( 1,2,3 )
GROUP BY c.conversation_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

That will ensure that all three users from the WHERE condition `uxc.user_id IN ( 1,2,3 )` are members of the conversation. But you will also need to ensure, that there are no other members. That can be done with a correlated `NOT EXISTS` subquery.

```
...
GROUP BY c.conversation_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
   AND NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT *
     FROM users_x_conversations uxc1
     WHERE uxc1.conversation_id = uxc.conversation_id
       AND uxc1.user_id NOT IN ( 1,2,3 )
   )
```

Another way would be to count all users from the conversation (which should also be `3` in this case).

```
...
GROUP BY c.conversation_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
   AND (
     SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM users_x_conversations uxc1
     WHERE uxc1.conversation_id = uxc.conversation_id
   ) = 3
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul (+1) - curious about the last line there (`HAVING COUNT(*) = 3`), what does that accomplish? I'm curious!

Comment: Sorry the query is not complete. `HAVING COUNT(*) = 3` will ensure that all three users from `WHERE uxc.user_id IN ( 1,2,3 )` are members of the conversation. But you will also need to ensure, that there are no other members.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use join for each user:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM conversations c
LEFT JOIN users_x_conversations uxc1 
   ON uxc1.user_id = 1 AND c.conversation_id = uxc1.conversation_id
LEFT JOIN users_x_conversations uxc2 
   ON uxc1.user_id = 2 AND c.conversation_id = uxc2.conversation_id
LEFT JOIN users_x_conversations uxc3 
   ON uxc1.user_id = 3 AND c.conversation_id = uxc3.conversation_id
WHERE uxc1.user_id is not null and ucx2.user_id is not null and ucx3.id is not null
Group by c.id
```